# How to replace multiple blank lines with a specific non-blank line?

Tags: sed, awk

The sample input is

```
1
2
3


4
5



6
7
8



9
```

The expected output is

```
1
2
3
---
4
5
---
6
7
8
---
9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
cat -s file | sed 's/^$/---/'
```

From man page of cat :

```
   -s, --squeeze-blank
          never more than one single blank line
```

Once `cat` has squeezed the blank lines, `sed` replaces the blank with with a `---`

Answer (score 4):

A POSIX-compliant approach using AWK's multi-line record capability (null RS):

```
awk 1 RS= ORS='\n---\n' file
```

This yields output identical to your desired output, except for a "---" line at the very end. If that discrepancy is unacceptable, it can be eliminated with a sed filter:

```
... | sed '$d'
```